# How to specify a css location except one area ? Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, triggers

Here is my view :

```
<body >
  <table class="table canvas" cellspacing=0 >
    <tr class="twenty">
      <th colspan=2>KP</th>
      <th colspan=2>KA</th>
      <th colspan=2>VP</th>
      <th colspan=2>CR</th>
      <th colspan=2>CS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="twenty" >
      <td rowspan=3 colspan=2 >
        <%= render @blocks[0]  %>
        </td>
      <td colspan=2> 
        <%= render @blocks[1]  %>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=3 colspan=2>
        <%= render @blocks[2]  %>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <%= render @blocks[3]  %>
      </td>
      <td rowspan=3 colspan=2>
        <%= render @blocks[4]  %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="twenty" >
      <th colspan=2>KR</th>
      <th colspan=2>CH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="twenty" >
      <td colspan=2>
        <%= render @blocks[5]  %>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <%= render @blocks[6]  %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fifty">
      <th colspan=5>C$</th>
      <th colspan=5>RS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fifty" >
      <td colspan=5>
        <%= render @blocks[7]  %>
      </td>
      <td colspan=5>
        <%= render @blocks[8]  %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Each render blocks[x] renders this :

```
<%= form_for block, :html => { :id => "block_"+block.id_case.to_s}  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :size => "5x4"  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id_case %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :canvas_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

So each form hash the id "block_1", "block_2" et cetera.

It creates forms like this :

```
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/blocks/11" class="edit_block" id="block_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Xztxw50P1m0GXd9yysJfZdvy+/6HRtd+RupVX09Qwt4=" /></div> 
  <textarea cols="5" id="block_content" name="block[content]" rows="4"> 
Development</textarea> 
  <input id="block_id_case" name="block[id_case]" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
  <input id="block_canvas_id" name="block[canvas_id]" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
</form>
```

My point is that when someone is currently writing in the textarea, as soon as he clicks somewhere else than the textarea, it clicks ont the "save" button.

I've written this little bit of javascript code to test :

```
var test=false;

$('form#block_1.edit_block textarea#block_content').click(function() {
test=true;
}
)


$('body').on('click', 'td', function(){
   if (test)
    {
      $('form#block_1.edit_block input').trigger('click');
      test=false
    }

});
```

But when I open my javascript console in Chrome, each time I try to click elsewhere than in the textarea, I receive this message :

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Someone can tell me where it comes from and how to fix it ? I am not very convenient with css location.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the 'click' event on `form#block_1.edit_block input` it acts the same as when you actually clicked on that element, triggering its own click event as well as the one of its parents, which includes `body`. Your script gets into an infinite loop:

```
$('body').on('click'
...
$('form#block_1.edit_block input').trigger('click');
...
$('body').on('click'
...
$('form#block_1.edit_block input').trigger('click');
...
```

hence the "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

On how to solve it: what are you trying to do exactly? You want to trigger some function if the user clicks anywhere but in the textarea?

### Update 1

I am not sure about what your code is doing but you can avoid the infinite loop by stopping the propagation of the event:

```
$('form#block_1.edit_block input').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Absolutely. I want that when someone is writing in the textarea, when he clicks outside the textarea, it saves what he just wrote by clicking on the save button.

Comment: Oops sorry, you should put the `stopPropagation` in the event handle of `form#block_1.edit_block input`

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
var test=false;
var alreadyInCallback = false;

$('form#block_1.edit_block textarea#block_content').click(function() {
test=true;
}
)


$('body').on('click', 'td', function(){
   if (test && !alreadyInCallback)
    {
      alreadyInCallback = true; 
      $('form#block_1.edit_block input').trigger('click');
      alreadyInCallback = false;
      test=false
    }
});
```

Comment: It has the effect to click on the button submit as soon as i click in the textarea.